# Maven dependencyManagement WARNING on clean project generated from start.spring.io

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm creating a Spring Boot 1.5.1 project from `start.spring.io` including the following dependencies: Web, HATEOAS, Stream Kafka, Zookeeper Configuration, Zookeeper Discovery, Actuator. The service itself is a spring-cloud-stream test service.

Without changing anything from the generated code, at `mvn package` I got the following message. It's just a warning, but since compiling other maven project I'm getting build problems in other projects I'd like to solve it. (I tried to isolate the problem by creating this clean project from start.spring.io).

This is the exact Warning log, and below the generated `pom.xml`. Notice that the dependencyManagement warning mentions `com.netflix.eureka`, but in this project no Eureka dependencies have been included.

I also tried to remove all contents from the local maven repository and rebuild, to make sure this is in a consistent state but kept getting the warning.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for eu.myapp.services.testsource:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, /home/vagrant/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 273, column 19
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

here the `pom.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.myapp.services.testsource</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies/pom.xml#L273-L276

I've opened an issue here. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1715

Comment: However the warnings shouldn't appear with Maven 3.2.1 or higher: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2315

Comment: If you're using the maven wrapper (as recommended) you would be using version 3.3.9

Comment: Yep. I just tried it with 3.1.1, 3.2.5 and the wrapper, and only 3.1.1 gives me the warning. So the OP seams to use that or an older version of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

it's very likely that the dependency is being used by another dependency I recommend you first find the issue by doing a search on your dependency tree.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

looks like spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery might be the culprit
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-zookeeper/

now it's just a matter of finding what is excluding it. What you do next might get tricky because if you exclude it, zookeeper might now work anymore

Comment: I tried to remove spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery from the dependencies, but still getting the warning (also removed spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config by the way, same result). Moreover, from the dependency:tree I see no reference to eureka.